# pytest: test doctests with of usage Python scripts

Tags: python, pytest

I like to keep in docstring of a Python script `rna_filter.py` usage like:

```
Usage::

  $ python rna_filter.py -r restraints.txt -s test_data/CG.pdb -v
  (d:A1-A2 <  10.0  1)|(d:A2-A1 <= 10 1)
  restraints [('A1', 'A2', '<', '10.0', '1'), ('A2', 'A1', '<=', '10', '1')]
```

is there any way to test it with pytest?

Edit: for me, this way of documenting my scripts is very convenient. For example, I know exactly what the script does, e.g. [rna_filter documentation](https://rna-pdb-tools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/utils.html#rna-filter-py-calculate-distances-based-on-given-restrants-on-pdb-files-or-simrna-trajectories) and I don't want to copy the code to `pytest`. I would to test them from the docstring.

Comment: I wrote something like this, for now, [doctest-cmds](https://github.com/mmagnus/doctest-cmds) but this is super basic, I wonder if anyone has done something like this before.

Comment: I found something more, but this does not work with pytest (I think) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9973895/python-doctest-for-shell-scripts-that-test-argument-parsing-without-polluting-do